# Are there diagnostic tools to isolate issue with "Invalid character value for cast specification" (Import dataframe from R to SQL)

Tags: sql, r, odbc

I am trying to write a dataframe from R to a SQL database. When I try to append the table to the SQL dataframe, I receive the following error:

Error in result_insert_dataframe(rs@ptr, values, batch_rows) :
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Invalid character value for cast specification

I understand that this is an issue with one of my field not being formatted correctly or containing incompatible values for SQL. However, it is a very large dataframe with multiple fields, and I am having trouble isolating which is the issue. Does anyone have a suggested workflow or diagnostic tools to help isolate the issue?

**Main Question: Are there diagnostic tools in R to help specify/identify which field is triggering an "invalid character value for cast specification" warning when trying to append a multi-variable dataframe in R to a SQL data table?**

Edit - here are the data types of the R dataframe compared with the target table:
[image: R Dataframe and Target SQL Table Data Types]

Comment: It's not clear what data you are writing, nor how the table is structured. Please make this question reproducible by giving more context. Thanks!

Comment: my bad, i hope my edits are helpful

Comment: Not entirely. What you _think_ a field is and what it really is could be different. Please add what the database says the fields should be, perhaps `dbGetQuery(con, "select column_name, data_type, character_maximum_length from information_schema.columns where table_name = 'remotetablename'")` (using the real table name). Paste the output from that into a [code block](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Thanks!

Comment: You actually just provided me the exact diagnostic tool I needed to figure out my issue. There was one variable that had a time format in SQL (I thought it was a character format). I really appreciate the snippet of code you provided me, and your patience.

Comment: FYI, `information_schema.columns` is useful and present in many DBMSes, though some more-knowledgeable DBAs may suggest "better" (more appropriate) methods for specific database vendors. It has been robust enough for me over the years, especially for more direct exploration like this. Glad it helped!